# Positioning a figcaption to be fixed to the bottom right of an image

Tags: html, css, image

I am looking to create a figcaption on top of an image that defaults to the bottom right of the image that is around 40% of the width of the image. 
Here is an image of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6V69.jpg

This is the code I have so far but can't seem to default to the right without overflowing:

```css
figure {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
}

figcaption {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    background: rgba(19, 43, 102, .85);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
 <figure>
    <img src="img/anImage.png">
    <figcaption>
        <h4>Blog Post</h4>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I scaled everything down but the solution remains the same. Change the `<figure>` like so:

> ```
>  figure {
>     margin: 0 auto;
>     display:table;
>     position: relative;
>   }
> ```

Set the `<img>` to `height:auto` either by attribute:

> `<img src...height='auto'>`

or by CSS stylesheet or `<style>` block

> `img {height:auto...}`

**SNIPPET**

```css
html,
body {
  font: 100 62.5%/1 Verdana;
}
figure {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}
figcaption {
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgba(19, 43, 102, .85);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width='200' height='auto'>
  <figcaption>
    <h4>Blog Post</h4>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<figure>` will be the full width of the container whereas the image will be its natural size.

You have two options.

1. Make the image full width (depends on styling of course)
2. Limit the width of the figure element

Option 1:

```
figure img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm making the assumption that you're already setting a max-width for images and removing it.

Option 2:

```
figure { 
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you're not already doing so you'll probably also want to set the images to `display: block;` and `vertical-align: top;` to iron out any minor misalignments.